# Task scheduler on windows server

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule a task which runs every 15 min during weekdays only. I've got the weekly option but confused what should I put in Recure every?
As I want to run this indefinitely till I manually stop it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the Create New Scheduled Task Wizard only lets you specify a single simple schedule, a single Task can still have multiple schedules, which you can configure after the task is created.

1. Open Task Scheduler > (your task) > (right-click) > Properties > Triggers
2. Then add remove the default trigger you set in the wizard.
3. Then add 5 separate schedule triggers for Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri as follows:

   - Begin the task: On a schedule
   - **Weekly**
   - Start: Midnight of tonight.
   - Recur every: **1 weeks**
   - On (a *single day* corresponding to the trigger, so choose Monday for the first one).
   - Advanced settings:

     - Repeat task every **15 minutes**

       - ...for a duration of **1 day**
       - [X] Stop all running tasks at end of repetition duration (just for safety)
     - [X] Stop task if it runs longer than (*X* minutes) (also for safety)
     - (Ensure "Expire" is *unchecked*)
     - [X] Enabled
4. Repeat Step 3 for Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.

So at the end, you should have something like this:

[image]